# How to let Eclipse JDT auto-generate methods at the end of the class?

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, preferences, eclipse-jdt

Is there a way to let Eclipse JDT (*Indigo* and newer) auto-generate methods at the end of the class, rather than as the next member, when you type the name of an unimplemented method?

Ideally, methods would still be auto-generated before getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to pull up the generate dialogs via `alt-shift-s` rather than just starting to type.  They have **Insertion Point** drop-downs that let you pick where the generated code goes.  Choose **Last member**.

Alternatively, you could always generate your code and then sort your members via `Source->Sort Members` but if you're incrementally adding to old code your team-mates might not like you checking in big changes like that into your repository.

Comment: I'm aware of the *Insertion Point* dropdowns, but am very fond of using the keyboard (and avoiding the mouse) whenever I can, so I was looking for an alternative to the menu- and view-based source alteration mechanisms.